# Displaying database records in android using JAVA RESTful webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I am trying to display database record using java restful web service. I have able to create a login form using it but I cannot display the records on the database. I tried this code but its not working at all. When button is pressed nothing happens. Heres my code.

DriverDetails.java

class Details extends Activity {

```
TextView name1;
TextView plate1;
Button Btngetdata;

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://192.168.254.108:8080/taxisafe/display/taxidetails";

//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_USER = "taxi";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "taxi_name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "taxi_plate_no";

JSONArray user = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new JSONParse().execute();

        }
    });

}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        plate1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.plate);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpConnection jParser = new HttpConnection();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            name1.setText(name);
            plate1.setText(email);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

HttpConnection.java

```
public class HttpConnection {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public HttpConnection() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding Volley to your project

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

and following the example here https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json

You will not need to create your own HTTP request. Let Volley handle the network request using JSONObjectRequest